# Not able to get right firebase storage package

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using:

```
flutter 2.2.3
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+2
firebase_core: ^0.5.3
firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
```

Which will be the correct firebase storage package as I get error while using the latest package.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use firebase_storage: ^10.0.3 and still not working then do invalid catch and restart the app.

Hope it's working for you.